# Angular 10: VScode errors out on absolute path for some directories, not others

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

Last week, VScode complained about not being able to resolve modules in every directory except my components directory. Now, it works fine for all directories except one that I created today (stores). I'm going nucking futz here. Everything compiles in Angular so it's not a TS error. It just seems to be that VScode can't figure out absolute paths (but somehow knows that SOME folders are 'legit')

I'm not doing any path aliasing (because I couldn't get THAT to work, either)

I've re-loaded my workspace and have restarted VScode.

I reinstalled VScode last week but it didn't solve the issue where only my components directory were showing errors. BUT sometime between then and now, it did start working.

I've upgraded to vscode 1.49.0 and the issue still persists.

In my models folder, components folder, (and all other folders), it prompts me for pathing as I type, and lints the path fine:
[image]

In my stores folder, it doesn't prompt for the path:
[image]

And it complains about not being able to load the module:
[image]

It's REALLY hard to concentrate on my project when my editor says things are broken when they're not. Does VScode cache workspace directory structures so it knows whether a path is kosher? and if so, can I manually refresh that cache when I add a new directory, if VScode isn't going to bother doing it for me?

Comment: This is either an index.ts issue or an app.module issue.

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2988 https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: Text doesn't show the linting underlines or the boxes that show up. I was demonstrating a failure of the tool.

Answer (score -1):

Well, i have faced this issue so instead of directly calling 'src' in path, I will suggest you to use '../../' directory browsing.